# Migration from opnesaml2 to opensaml4

Tags: spring-security, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

We are using opensaml-2.6.6 version, esapi-2.3.0.0 version and spring-security-saml2-core - 1.0.9 currently in our project. We are planning to upgrade to opensaml-core-4.0.1 version.
We have searched for the support for migration and we were not able to find documentation/guide available

Is there any documentation/guide from opensaml2 to opensaml4 or community forum to help us in migration.

We tried changing opensaml2.6.6 to opensaml-core-4.0.1 version and there were 24 classes which were getting compilation errors due to classes not found, package not found, etc.